# Neptune JDBC connectivity With IAM authentication throwing exception "NoSuchMethod"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gremlin, amazon-neptune, neptune

I am trying to fetch table metadata from Amazon Neptune using Neptune JDBC Driver. Our Neptune is IAM authentication enabled.

```
            System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", AwsConstants.ACCESS_KEY);
            System.setProperty("aws.secretKey", AwsConstants.SECRET_KEY);
            System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", "software.aws.neptune.NeptuneDriver");
        
            
            String url = "jdbc:neptune:gremlin://" + AwsConstants.ENDPOINT;

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("authScheme", "IAMSigV4");
            properties.put("port", 8182);
            properties.put("serviceRegion", AwsConstants.REGION);
            properties.put("enableSsl", true);
            properties.put("logLevel", "ALL");
            
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);

            List<String> vertex = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> edge = new ArrayList<>();

            DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
            ResultSet results = metaData.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
            
            GremlinSchema gremlinSchema = MetadataCache.getGremlinSchema(AwsConstants.ENDPOINT);
            SqlMetadata sqlMetadata = new SqlMetadata(gremlinSchema);
```

I have included below dependencies.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.neptune</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-neptune-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-neptune-sigv4-signer</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1009</version>
        </dependency>
```

For above set of jar, I am getting below exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.SigV4WebSocketChannelizer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
    ... 4 more
```

But if I add below dependency,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>amazon-neptune-gremlin-java-sigv4</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

then getting below exception about NoSuchMehtod.

```
23/11/09 15:34:44 [gremlin-driver-loop-1] WARN channel.ChannelInitializer: Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0x0289e5ec]

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketClientHandler: method 'void <init>(io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker)' not found

    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.createHandler(SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.java:212)

    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.configure(SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.java:176)

    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Channelizer$AbstractChannelizer.initChannel(Channelizer.java:137)

    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Channelizer$AbstractChannelizer.initChannel(Channelizer.java:83)
```

On the maven central, amazon-neptune-jdbc-driver jar with version 3.0.0 is present, but same exception is getting thrown even though I use 3.0.1 or 3.0.2 version jar.

Can someone help in identifying the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a conflict with some of your dependency versions. `SigV4WebSocketChannelizer` was the old method of handling IAM auth for gremlin. This Channelizer does not work with the latest versions of TinkerPop.

My recommendation would be to try version 3.0.2 as this is the most up to date build, and use it with TinkerPop 3.6.4 if possible (this is the intended TP version for 3.0.2).

Let me know if TP 3.5.6 is required for other reasons and I can look for a resolution which includes it.

Comment: Actually Neptune engine version is 1.2.0.0 and as per "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-client.html" maximum thinker pop version supported is 3.5.6 , so we are using 3.5.6 version. I tried same 3.0.2 with gremlin 3.5.6 but it was also throwing same exception.

Comment: While Neptune 1.2.0.0 does not support TinkerPop 3.6, this incompatibility largely refers to old Neptune engines not supporting new gremlin features such as mergeV(). The JDBC driver uses portions of TinkerPop which have not changed much between versions, and remains functional with older Neptune engines.

JDBC 3.0.2 has been tested against Neptune 1.2.0.0 using TP 3.6.4. JDBC 3.0.2 has not been tested using versions of TinkerPop other than the intended version.

Comment: Tried with TinkerPop 3.6.4 and 3.0.2 driver version. But its throwing exception "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class software.aws.neptune.NeptuneDriver" even though class is present in the class loader along with all the required jars.

Comment: It's possible that an error is taking place during class initialization which is leading to the NoClassDefFoundError despite the class being present on the classpath. Are there any nested or previous errors which may indicate why the class failed to load?